# Android: I have created a new activity, I called it but the window doesn't have the GUI

Tags: android, android-activity

(I am running this on a Nexus 7) I created a new activity and I have called on it properly. The new window appears correctly, except none of the GUI elements that I declared int eh XML file appear in this new window. How do I fix that?

In my main activity:

```
    final Intent mapIntent = new Intent(this, MapActivity.class);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);
    Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.MapButton);//Finds the button w/id "MapButton"
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            startActivity(mapIntent);   
        }
    });
```

And the called activity (MapActivity) is empty except for the super.onCreate(SavedInstanceState) line in onCreate().

Comment: By posting relevant code...

Comment: can you post your code plase?

Comment: Can you post the XML as well. Also, I think you may need `new View.OnClickListener()` in the setter method.

Comment: Is the code you posted from the `Activity` that isn't displaying or is it after you press `b`?

Comment: show the MapActivity code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me guess: you didn't call `setContentView(R.id.xml_file_layout)` in your Activity `onCreate()` - just after the call to `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)`!

Comment: Why the downvote? .... it was a correct guess in the end. You can also mark this [answer as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set the layout in MapActivity. 
`setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);`

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling super() then always place it properly, just 1st line of the method. Hope this will help you, if you have correctly get what I'm saying.